# count the permutation which have $k$ maxima

Tags: permutations, recurrence-relations

I need some help for the following homework question.

A permutation $P (\pi_1\pi_2...\pi_n)$ of {$1,2,...,n$} is given. We say that $j$ is a maxima of $P$ whenever $\pi_j$>$j$. How can I find recurrence relation to count the number of $n$-permutations of {$1,2,...,n$} that have exactly $k$ maxima?

Please provide some hints to solve the problem.

A hint was given that this count is related to Stirling Number of First kind.

Comment: Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of permutations of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ that have exactly $k$ maxima.

Consider a permutation $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n$ of $1,2,\ldots, n$. The number of permutations that have $a_n=n$ and have exactly $k$ maxima is simply $f(n-1,k)$, since $n$ cannot be one of the $k$ maxima. I am not sure how to handle the case $a_n \ne n$ though...

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. I thought of subtracting $1$ from the total count when $a_n$ $\ne$ $n$ with the same recurrence. But that's not true I guess.

Comment: So maybe you should look up the recurrence for the Stirling numbers, and see whether you can show that the permutations you want to count satisfy the same recurrence.